# Grails: How to do Database Migration with MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, grails, migration

The Grails [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) does not work with MongoDB.

**Is there any alternative way to do database migration with mongoDB?**

Answer (score 2):

What kind of migrations do you want to do?
As MongoDB has dynamic schemas, adding or removing fields is not a problem. Simply add or remove them in your domain classes and you are good to go. Fields which do not exist in a specific document are evaluated to `null`. In case you need a different default value, use the according service to set or get them. Another solution would be to [use GORM events and implement according handlers](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) to set the according return values `onLoad` when loading the object and/or `onUpdate` when saving the value.

Comment: I'd assume that it is easier to use than `Bootstrap.groovy` if you have a lot of static data to insert or if static data is added during the application lifetime. Other than that, I do not see the point in mongeez in general and for Grails in particular.

Comment: One thing that you may want to do is move data from one collection to another.  For example, an embedded array is getting too large and you revise your data model to keep that data in a separate collection.  You migrate that data once.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/mongeez

PS: I haven't used it but it should do what you need.

Comment: This plugin is outdated. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Did you try using it? Didn't work? There are many plugins which might not be updated from long and that may be because they are stable.

Comment: Well but there is still a newer version of mongeez which is not included in the plugin